# Changing a password with one command in FreeBSD

Tags: passwords, freebsd, user-accounts, change-password

How can I, as a simple user, change my own password with one command (in one line) in FreeBSD. I tried using `passwd --stdin` but that seems like it's a Linux command only.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `pw` command to take input from STDIN like this:

```
echo "mynewpassword" | pw usermod admin -h 0
```

See `man pw` for more details.

Answer (score -2):

Just type `passwd` and follow the prompts.

Also `man 1 passwd` for documentation.

Update with a copy of my comment, below, from September 2013:

The whole point about passwd is to make that hard for automated password changers to guess passwords. If you have a port like expect on the system you could script it. If you are root, you could use pw usermod username -h0. If you're just an ordinary user, just do it interactively.

Comment: i want to do it in one command, in one line. something like `echo "old:new:new" | passwd user`

Comment: The whole point about `passwd` is to make that hard for automated password changers to guess passwords. If you have a port like `expect` on the system you could script it. If you are root, you could use `pw usermod username -h0`. If you're just an ordinary user, just do it interactively